# MySQL - Using condition from inside a select

Tags: mysql, select, parameters, conditional-statements

I've got 3 tables:

- orders:

  - orders_id
  - date_purchased
  - ...
- orders_products:

  - orders_products_id
  - orders_id
  - products_id
  - products_name
  - products_quantity
  - ...
- products_warehouses:

  - products_id
  - warehouses_id
  - product_quantity_in_warehouse

Now I want a table with the following information:

- current_date
- products_id
- products_name
- warehouses_id
- current_quantity_in_warehouse
- sold_yesterday

I've got the following so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  CURRENT_DATE AS `date`
                 orpr.products_id AS products_id
                 orpr.products_name AS products_name
                 pwq.warehouses_id AS warehouses_id
                 pwq.products_quantity AS current_quantity_in_warehouse
                 (  SELECT SUM(orpr.products_quantity)
                    FROM `products_warehouses` wpq
                    INNER JOIN `orders_products` orpr ON pwq.products_id = orpr.products_id
                    INNER JOIN `orders` or ON orpr.orders_id = or.orders_id
                    WHERE pwq.products_id = ??
                    AND   pwq.warehouses_id = ?? ) AS sold_yeserday
FROM             `orders_products` orpr
INNER JOIN       `orders` or ON orpr.orders_id = or.orders_id
INNER JOIN       `products_warehouses pwq ON pwq.products_id = orpr.products_id;
```

What I want is at the place of the ??'s the products_id and warehouses_id simular to each row of the result.

If someone got an easier exmaple of how to use a select inside a select (from which the inner select uses a where-condition id from the select its in, which changes each row of course), it's also fine, as long as I can reproduce the example to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance,

Greetz,
Kevin C

Comment: This sounds like a correlated subquery, which has some performance concerns. It might be easier to transform it into a join against this aggregate: `JOIN (SELECT products_id, warehouses_id, SUM(products_quantity) GROUP BY products_id, warehouses_id)`.

Comment: Can you us a preview of some dummy data of your expected output? and if possible a sample of your current progress on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) thanks

Comment: http://ideone.com/5sb68 Since SQL-fiddle only allowed 8000 or less characters I posted the Inserts on ideone.com. I removed all unneeded data for my problem, and replaced the productnames because of privacy reasons. (The 16206 and 2 should be replaced with the current ids of that row).

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the inner SELECT-statement and put the reult in a table and you can join with that table in your outer select

```
SELECT SUM(orpr.products_quantity) As 'Sold_yesterday', pwd.products_id, pwd.warehouses_id
INTO #tempTable
FROM `products_warehouses` wpq
INNER JOIN `orders_products` orpr ON pwq.products_id = orpr.products_id
INNER JOIN `orders` or ON orpr.orders_id = or.orders_id


SELECT DISTINCT  CURRENT_DATE AS `date`
orpr.products_id AS products_id
orpr.products_name AS products_name
pwq.warehouses_id AS warehouses_id
pwq.products_quantity AS current_quantity_in_warehouse                
FROM             `orders_products` orpr
INNER JOIN       `orders` or ON orpr.orders_id = or.orders_id
INNER JOIN       `products_warehouses pwq ON pwq.products_id = orpr.products_id;
INNER JOIN       '#tempTable' tt On tt.products_id = pwd.products_id AND tt.warehouses_id = pwd.warehouses_id
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it gave me an error at the #tempTable part.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_DATE AS `date`,
    orpr.products_id AS products_id,
    orpr.products_name AS products_name,
    pwq.warehouses_id AS warehouses_id,
    pwq.products_quantity AS current_quantity_in_warehouse,
    SUM(orpr.products_quantity) AS sold_yeserday
FROM             
    orders_products orpr
    INNER JOIN       
    products_warehouses pwq ON pwq.products_id = orpr.products_id;
group by orpr.products_id, pwq.warehouses_id
order by orpr.products_id, pwq.warehouses_id
```